# Fully parameterized PowerShell function for file removal

Tags: powershell

I would like your opinion on my `Remove-Files` PowerShell function. It is used in my [*File-Removal-PowerShell-Script*](https://github.com/Zoran-Jankov/File-Removal-PowerShell-Script). It is designed to be very flexible so a script user can have configure it to remove files in multiple and various way as it often the chase.

#### Remove-Files function

```
function Remove-Files {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $FolderPath,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $FileName,

        [Parameter(Position = 2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [int]
        $OlderThen = 0,

        [Parameter(Position = 3, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $Recurse = "false",

        [Parameter(Position = 4, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $Force = "false"
    )

    begin {
        $DateToDelete = (Get-Date).AddDays(- $OlderThen)
    }

    process {
        $FolderSpaceFreed = 0
        $FilesRemoved = 0
        $FailedRemovals = 0

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) {
            Write-Log -Message "ERROR: $FolderPath folder does not exist"
            return
        }

        $FullPath = Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath $FileName

        if ($Recurse -eq "true") {
            $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath -Recurse
        }
        else {
            $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath
        }

        $FileList = $FileList | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateToDelete}

        foreach ($File in $FileList) {
            $FileSize  = (Get-Item -Path $File.FullName).Length
            $SpaceFreed = Get-FormattedFileSize -Size $FileSize

            if ($Force -eq "true") {
                Get-Item -Path $File.FullName | Remove-Item -Force
            }
            else {
                Get-Item -Path $File.FullName | Remove-Item
            }

            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $File.FullName)) {
                $Message = "Successfully deleted " + $File.Name + " file - removed $SpaceFreed"
                $FolderSpaceFreed += $FileSize
                $FilesRemoved ++
            }
            else {
                $Message = "Failed to delete " + $File.Name + " file"
                $FailedRemovals ++
            }
            Write-Log -Message $Message
        }

        $SpaceFreed = Get-FormattedFileSize -Size $FolderSpaceFreed

        if ($FilesRemoved -gt 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "Successfully deleted $FilesRemoved files in $FolderPath folder, and $SpaceFreed of space was freed"
        }
        if ($FailedRemovals -gt 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "Failed to delete $FailedRemovals files in $FolderPath folder"
        }
        if ($FilesRemoved -eq 0 -and $FailedRemovals -eq 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "No files for delition were found in $FolderPath folder"
        }
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            FolderSpaceFreed =  $FolderSpaceFreed
            FilesRemoved = $FilesRemoved
            FailedRemovals = $FailedRemovals
        }
    }
}
```

Before someone says anything about it, I have to tell you why I did not use a `switch` type for `-Recurse` and `-Force` parameters, and it is because the function is feed from `.csv` file with data, and I did not find a elegant way to pass string value to a `switch` parameter.

Comment: `… -Force:$($Force -eq "true")` is a possible way to pass a `[string]$Force` value to the `-Force` switch parameter…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to use pass string values to switch parameters to `Remove-Files` function so I have refactored the function ho have two switch parameters.

### The new version

```
function Remove-Files {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0,
                   ParameterSetName = "FolderPath",
                   ValueFromPipeline = $false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   HelpMessage = "Full folder path in which file/files are to be deleted")]
        [string]
        $FolderPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1,
                   ParameterSetName = "FileName",
                   ValueFromPipeline = $false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   HelpMessage = "File name that can include wildcard character")]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string]
        $FileName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   Position = 2,
                   ParameterSetName = "OlderThen",
                   ValueFromPipeline = $false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   HelpMessage = "Number of days to delete files older than that")]
        [int]
        $OlderThen = 0,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   Position = 3,
                   ParameterSetName = "Recurse",
                   ValueFromPipeline = $false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   HelpMessage = "Switch on to file remove files in subfolders")]
        [switch]
        $Recurse = $false,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   Position = 4,
                   ParameterSetName = "Force",
                   ValueFromPipeline = $false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   HelpMessage = "Switch on to force remove files")]
        [switch]
        $Force = $false
    )

    process {
        $FolderSpaceFreed = 0
        $FilesRemoved = 0
        $FailedRemovals = 0

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) {
            Write-Log -Message "ERROR: $FolderPath folder does not exist"
            return
        }

        $FullPath = Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath $FileName

        if ($Recurse) {
            $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath -Recurse
        }
        else {
            $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath 
        }

        $DateToDelete = (Get-Date).AddDays(- $OlderThen)

        $FileList = $FileList | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $DateToDelete}

        foreach ($File in $FileList) {
            $FileSize  = (Get-Item -Path $File.FullName).Length
            $SpaceFreed = Get-FormattedFileSize -Size $FileSize

            if ($Force) {
                Get-Item -Path $File.FullName | Remove-Item -Force
            }
            else {
                Get-Item -Path $File.FullName | Remove-Item
            }

            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $File.FullName)) {
                $Message = "Successfully deleted " + $File.Name + " file - removed $SpaceFreed"
                $FolderSpaceFreed += $FileSize
                $FilesRemoved ++
            }
            else {
                $Message = "Failed to delete " + $File.Name + " file"
                $FailedRemovals ++
            }
            Write-Log -Message $Message
        }

        $SpaceFreed = Get-FormattedFileSize -Size $FolderSpaceFreed

        if ($FilesRemoved -gt 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "Successfully deleted $FilesRemoved files in $FolderPath folder, and $SpaceFreed of space was freed"
        }
        if ($FailedRemovals -gt 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "Failed to delete $FailedRemovals files in $FolderPath folder"
        }
        if ($FilesRemoved -eq 0 -and $FailedRemovals -eq 0) {
            Write-Log -Message "No files for delition were found in $FolderPath folder"
        }
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            FolderSpaceFreed =  $FolderSpaceFreed
            FilesRemoved = $FilesRemoved
            FailedRemovals = $FailedRemovals
        }
    }
}
```